# Django: Error while installing "Django Registration Redux"

Tags: django, django-registration

I am trying to install "Django Registration Redux".
I followed every step in the [official website](http://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) to install.

When I am installing `django.contrib.sites`, the admin doesn't work, and when I comment this the admin starts working but registration does not work in either way.

It gives the error as:

```
DoesNotExist at /accounts/login/
Site matching query does not exist.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/
Django Version: 1.9
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Site matching query does not exist.
Exception Location: c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in get, line 387
Python Executable:  c:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.11
Python Path:    
['E:\\myproject\\mysite',
 'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
 'c:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'c:\\Python27\\lib',
 'c:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'c:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'c:\\Python27',
 'c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 24 May 2016 13:26:56 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't followed the instructions to [enable the sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework).

After adding `django.contrib.sites` to `INSTALLED_APPS`, you need to set `SITE_ID = 1` in your settings, then run the `migrate` command.

Comment: i think it was not in the documentation

Comment: If you think the redux docs could be improved, then you could open an issue, or even better write a patch. A link to the `django.contrib.sites` docs would probably be best, rather than duplicating the instructions in the redux docs.